# Passing Spanish Language Data through JSON

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json, foursquare

I am fetching location data from `foursquare api` and then passing this data to `webservice` to insert in the `database`.

Now e.g. when i get location data for **Mexico** city then there are some **special characters** in it which gives following error:-

```
 Unrecognized escape sequence. (13443):
```

Right now i am using following encoding for JSON parsing:-

```
 NSString *requestString =  [jsonstring UTF8String];
```

How can i parse Special character(**Spanish Data**) e.g **Éspanol** in **JSON**?

Any solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Send/use the JSON with the correct encoding (UTF-8?).

Comment: @Paul Can you specify which type of encoding would be required for the above string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also having the same issue earlier with json. I solved this special character issue by using the following code:-

```
+(NSString *)http_post_method_changed:(NSString *)url content:(NSString *)jsonContent
{
NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:20.0f];
NSData *requestData = [jsonContent dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[theRequest setValue:@"application/json; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: requestData];
NSURLResponse *theResponse = NULL;
NSError *theError = NULL;
NSData *theResponseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&theResponse error:&theError];
NSString *data=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:theResponseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"url to send request= %@",url);
NSLog(@"response1111:-%@",data);
return data;
}
```

Pass your url and json to send and it will provide you the desired response.

Comment: I don't think a synchronous request is desirable. This will block the UI.

Comment: You can send it in background easily then it will not block the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use this?

```
NSArray *dataArray =
  [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_data
                                  options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                                    error:&error];
```

Make sure (by consulting the forsquare api docs) that the feed is indeed in UTF-8 - then the above should work without errors.

This assumes the API feed is sending you an array, use `NSDictionary` otherwise.